# appcompat-21 Drawer And Back Arrow Size differs in size

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I am using appcompat 21 as support library and using toolbar. The problem i am facing is the back arrow when drawer is open and the back arrow of activity set using

> getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

are differ in size.

I am not using any image for that. Just using native controls and coding for drawer back arrow and activity back arrow.

For detail please see the attached screen shots.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure why that happens, but I have a suggestion: You can use new `Toolbar` API. `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.what_ever_icon_u_have);` By using this you are using your own icon, so no need to worry about the size.